# Please only give me a feedback:) Verifying my solution - the differentiablity problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

> $\mathbf{Question:}$
>   Let $r>0$, $f: B_r(0) \to \Bbb R$.
>   Suppose there exists an  $\alpha >1$  such that $|f(x)| \le \|x\|^{\alpha }$ for all $x \in B_r(0)$
>
> (a) Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$
>
> (b) What happens to the result if $\alpha =1$ ?

$\mathbf{Solution:}$ 
In order to show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$, I need to show that all first partial derivative of f at $0$ exists and is continious at zero by a theorem.

Then, by the squeeze theorem, since $|f(x)| \le \|x\| \to 0 $ as $ x \to 0$, $f(0)=0$

Thus, $$\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(0)\right|= \lim_{h \to 0}\left|\frac{f(0,0,...,h,..,0)-f(0)}{h}\right|\le \lim_{h \to 0} |h|^{\alpha -1}=0 $$ since $\alpha >1$

i.e. The first partial derivative of $f$ exists at zero.

We see that $f_{x_j}(0)=0$ for $j=1,\ldots,m$. That's $\nabla f(0)=0$

$$\left|\frac {f(0+h)-f(0)- \nabla f(0). h}{\|h\|}\right|=\frac{|f(h)|}{\|h\|}\le \|h\|^{\alpha -1} \to 0$$ as $h \to 0$.

i.e all partial derivatives of $f$ is continuous at zero

Hence, $f$ is differentiable at $0$

---

When $\alpha = 1$, $f(x)=\|x\|$. Then $f_{x}(0,0)= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac {|h|}{h} $ DNE

Thus, f is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ for $\alpha =1$

---

Please can somebody verify my solution? Hopefully there is no mistake or omission! Thank you for helping:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see justification for your claim that "When $\alpha=1$, $f(x) = \|x\|$." I think you want $|f(x)|\leq \|x\|$. I think no conclusion can be reached when $\alpha =1$. For instance, if $r<1$, $n=2$, $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, then $|f(x,y)|\leq \|(x,y)\|$, but $f$ is differentiable at zero, with $\nabla f= 0$. If, on the other hand, $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then the inequality still holds (in fact, equality holds), but the function is not differentiable at zero.

Comment: Hmm.. Okay! I will pay more attention to solve the question. Thanks!